# Why is this appending multiple times? AJAX

Tags: ajax, append

I have this ajax function.  It gets the value of a textarea, sets it as a variable, and then sends that off to instagram.  It works.

I want to append the text area value to a div to show the comment posted, without refreshing the page.  It's basically a temporary visible comment that will be replaced with the actual comment from instagram when the page is reloaded.

First, ignore that what I am trying to do is in the error field of all of this.  Because I am working locally, success doesn't work, it's swapped.  Doesn't matter right now.

The problem I am having is when I append the data from the text area, it appends it multiple times.  I am currently displayed 4 images from instagram on my page.  It will append the text area data 4 times, on each photo, not sending the data to isntagram, just appending the fake comment.

If i remove 2 images from instagram, it will append it two times, for each image...  Why is it doing this, and how can I make it so when you submit the form, it appends the image, once, to that div.

Here is my function for submitting comments.

```
function instaComment(){

    $('.messageTextarea').keydown(function() {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            this.form.submit();
            return false;
         }
    });

    $('.button').live('click', function(){


        var name = $(this).siblings('.messageTextarea').val();
        var dataString = name;

        $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
          url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/"+$(this).attr('data-the_id')+"/comments?"+hash,
          type: "POST",
          data: "text="+dataString,
          success: function(data) {
              // finish load
            console.log(data, dataString, 'succ');
          },
            error: function(data) {
                for (i=0; i < instadata[0].data.length; i++){
                    var username = instadata[0].data[i].user.username;
                    var profilepic = instadata[0].data[i].user.profile_picture;

                    console.log(data, dataString, 'succ');
                    $(this).each(function() {
                        $('.messageComments').append('<li><img class="commentUserImg" src="' + profilepic + '"><div class="commentUser">' + username + '</div><div class="commentText">' + dataString + '</div></li>');
                    });


                }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but i think your problem come from this line of code

```
  $(this).each(function() {
                        $('.messageComments').append('<li><img class="commentUserImg" src="' + profilepic + '"><div class="commentUser">' + username + '</div><div class="commentText">' + dataString + '</div></li>');
                    });
```

Comment: That's what I am thinking as well... But I have no idea why, or how to fix it.